# How can I instantiate a controller manually based on a url without controller name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a CMS that stores the URL of a "page" in the database. The page has a reference to a template, which is just a regular aspx file. Using URL rewriting the request is sent to the  correct aspx file.

We got MVC support almost completed, but there is one problem. Everything in mvc is based on routing, which expects a controller name in the url (yes, I know you can set a default controller for urls without a controller name, but all the pages can have different controllers), which makes it hard to support url's of the following format:

www.domain.com/pagename

For example:

www.cnn.com/about-this-site

www.cnn.com/press-release-new-ceo-announced

The pagename has nothing to do with the controller or the view/action, it's just a url-friendly version of the page name.

So basically what we would like to do is to take the pagename, find the correct page our system, find the referenced template(controller in mvc) and set up manual routing for that controller and action. Any ideas on how to do that? Or should be just accept that URL's in mvc needs the controller name in most cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything in mvc is based on routing, which expects a controller name in the url

this is simply not true. Yes, that is the default simpliest behavious, which you can use out of the box. But routing is in no way limited to this, nor MVC. You can (and in your case you should) create custom route handling logic, by any of the following :

- Custom route constraint - make yourself a custom IRouteConstraint, which you will use on your route handling your content pages served by one particular "content" controller
- Custom RouteHandler - this is more advanced solution, if you want something really special, but from your question, you do not

If you are planning to have more than one "content-page" handling controller, and you want to choose it from routing data against DB, you have to implement custom ControllerFactory - that is the place where is in MVC stack decided, which controller will be used. There are plenty of examples of this, just google custom controller factory.